# Reporting Services 2008 - Can you link 2 datasets together?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to be able to join 2 datasets together. I can't do it in a query because each dataset comes from very difference datasources (one is SQL Server 05 and the other is IBM iSeries). And I can't do it via a master/subreport set up for various reasons.

If I can't join 2 datasets together I may resort to building and referencing a custom assembly to do my information lookups in the iSeries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must join them somehow you can look at writing a custom data processing extension. This also may be a more elegant method than a custom assembly as it fits the architecture a little better.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152816.aspx